# How can I view the Amp-State for a given component?

Tags: amp-html

The AMP playground has a nifty tool to look at the Amp-State.

Look at the State Tab in the playground:
https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fcomponents%2Famp-bind.example.1.html%3Fformat%3Dwebsites

Are there any dev tools that can show what the Amp State would be for my Amp Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable AMP debug by adding `#development=1` to the page address.
2. Open Developer Tools in your browser (usually by pressing F12)
3. In the Console tab, type `AMP.printState()`.

This will show something like `[amp-bind] {burger: 'open'}`.

Source: [AMP documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind#debugging-state)